# ORACLE SQL SELECT statement from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am a bit new to the world of oracle and sql and need some guidance. The problem at hand asks me to display name, nickname, and department name for all `employees not in department number 20 or 30`.

These categories come from different tables as follows.

`name` from table `names01`

`nickname` from table `nicks01`

`deptname` from `depts01`

`deptnumber` from table `depts01`

How do you create a `SELECT` statement to display these 3 field from different tables?

Comment: When you must obtain data from multiple tables to present in the same result set, you are ordinarily looking to `JOIN` those tables together into an aggregate table from which to select the results that satisfy the selection predicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name, b.nickname, .... from names01 a, nicks01 b, .....
```

The rest is left an exercise for the OP

Note that you referenced 4 tables but your description said 3 tables :)